# Help! How to Exit emergency mode ubuntu

Tags: boot

How to exit emergency mode

You are in emergency mode

I entered fsck /dev/sda1
Not work
/dev/sda1 is mounted
e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting.

Vi /etc/fstab

/dev/sda1  / errors=remount-ro

I don't know where is the problem

sudo fsck not solve the problem not continue reppair disk

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda1: clean, 265502/1831424 files, 1600773/7323974 blocks

mint@mint:~$ sudo fsck -nf /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda1: 265502/1831424 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 1600773/7323974 blocks
```

Comment: no I'm using linux mint

Answer (score 2):

You can't [fsck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fsck.8.html) a volume while it is mounted.

Try: `fsck -nf /dev/sda1`

- '-n' will dry-run which means it won't write anything & the '-f' will force it as often it will report clean. like a false positive.

Try to run fsck from a [live disc or USB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0).

Comment: sudo fsck -nf /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda1: 265502/1831424 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 1600772/7323974 blocks 

not worked with me

Comment: Please make a LiveUSB for LiveDVD from the ISO of whatever Ubuntu version you are using (and which version is that?), if you don't have one already from your installation. Boot from that so you can then run `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` to actually fix whatever's amiss. When that completes, put the results in your original question with [edit] instead of using Add Comment, because there's no formatting in a Comment.